# How can i connect my mobile app to mysql database in domain using jdbc?

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I recently bought domain and hosting to godaddy.com for my thesis project under cpanel type. I already uploaded my database. However, I can not connect my mobile app to the database using Android Studio as IDE with jdbc as a connector and nox player as an emulator.

I already tried checking my database's username and password.

Here is my Connection Class
'''
public class ConnClass {

```
String clazz="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String url="jdbc:mysql://realclinic.com/dbclinic";

//Already tried the following but none of these work
//String url="realclinic.com:3306/";
//String url="xxx.xx.xx.xxx.xx/dbclinic";
//String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbclinic";

//This exact IP code run fine but only when I tested it on same device(PC)
//String url="jdbc:mysql://123.456.7.8/dbclinic";

String dbusername="clinic";
String dbpassword="951736482";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN()
{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn=null;
    String ConnURL=null;
    try{
        Class.forName(clazz);
        conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url,dbusername,dbpassword);
        //conn=DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    }
    catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
```

'''

And here is my main activity code

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ConnClass cc;
DataClass dc=new DataClass();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    cc = new ConnClass();

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Dologin dologin = new Dologin();
            dologin.execute();
        }
    });
}

    private class Dologin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        String user=txtuser.getText().toString();
        String pass=txtpass.getText().toString();
        String msger="Oops";
        Boolean isSuccess=false;

        String dataReader_user,dataReader_pass;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            if(user.equals("") || pass.equals(""))
            {
                msger="Please fill up";
            }
            else
            {
                try{
                    Connection con=cc.CONN();
                    if(con==null)
                    {
                        msger="Please Check your Internet Connection";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String query="select * from parents_accts where Username='"+user+"' and Password='"+pass+"' ";
                        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);

                        while(rs.next())
                        {
                            qwer=rs.getRow();
                            dataReader_user=rs.getString(1);
                            dataReader_pass=rs.getString(2);


                            if(dataReader_user.equals(user) && dataReader_pass.equals(pass))
                            {
                                isSuccess=true;
                                msger="Log in Success";
                                dc.setAcct(user,pass,dataReader_lname,dataReader_fname,dataReader_mname);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                isSuccess=false;
                                msger="Invalid Acct";
                            }


                        }
                        rs.close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    isSuccess=false;
                    msger="Exception" + ex;
                }
            }
            return msger;


        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String a){

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+msger+String.valueOf(qwer),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(isSuccess==true)
            {

                Intent startIntent=new Intent(Login.this, PatientLists.class);

                startActivity(startIntent);
                //finish();
            }


        }
    }
```

'''

The program should shift to another page once the connection is successful but it returns me "Please check your internet connection" as toast instead.

I'm really at lost here, could anyone tell me what is the right syntax for my conection string here? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you get from Log.e() in logcat ?

Comment: Are you sure that realclinic.com has/listen on open port 3306 ?

Comment: com.example.realclinic E/ERRO: Could not create connection to database server.

com.example.realclinic E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'javax.naming.StringRefAddr', referenced from method com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.storeTo
these two are red in my logcat

Comment: actually i dont know which port it is. i just tried it if it can work, by the way how can i check which port is it? maybe that's what im doing wrong

Comment: That depends on the hosting plan of realclinic.com. Do you have a control panel or shell access to this host ? Maybe install MySQLWorkbench to see if it is reachable from the Internet.

Comment: `Could not create connection to database server` that could be any network issue between your device and your MySQL server.

Comment: yeah you're right, i contact their customer support and told me that that ip addresses that connects to my database are not yet allowed. thanks for pointing it out sir, really thanks.